Symplectic form on $\mathbb{CP}^n$
Undergrad student here. I'm working my way through differential geometry and now I'm studying de Rham cohomology. I'd like to find explicit generators for the de Rham cohomology of $\mathbb{CP}^n$ (with real coefficients). Thanks to its CW strutture I know $H^k$ Is $\mathbb{R}$ when k is even and 0 otherwise. I also know for a fact that $\mathbb{CP}^n$ admits a symplectic structure, which is perfect because being it also compact and without boundary, once I find $\omega$ a symplectic 2-form this will generate $H^2$ and $\omega^k$ will generate $H^{2k}$. Before I go any further, I want to be VERY clear in saying that I know nothing about complex geometry, let alone Khaler manifolds and whatnot. I was hoping I could approach this exclusively (and not necessairly elegantly) using differential geometry. Is there any hope?

are you asking for an explicit formula for $\omega$?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%E2%80%93Study_metric

@user8268 I think I'd be satisfied with less. For example, I've read you can construct it by first considering some form on the sphere, observing this form is invariant under the action of $\mathbb{S}^1$ and then considering some "induced" form on the projective space. This would be enough if the construction were clear and more or less precise.

@MoisheKohan thanks for the reference, however in that article It's not clear to me what the symplectic form is even at the level of the sphere, since it seems to only refer to metric.

This means that you have not read far enough in the article.

you can take the symplectic form $dx_1\wedge dy_1+\dots+ dx_{n+1}\wedge dy_{n+1}$ on $\mathbb C^{n+1}$ (here $z_k=x_k + i y_k$) and restrict it to the unit sphere $S^{2n-1}$; this form descends to $\mathbb{CP}^n$ in the sense that it is the pullback of a form (your symplectic form) from $\mathbb{CP}^n$ to $S^{2n-1}$

A symplectic form can be obtained as the curvature of a complex line bundle over $\mathbb{P}^n$: to any point in $\mathbb{P}^n$ corresponds a complex line $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$, and this defines the bundle (usually denoted $\mathcal{O}(-1)$, the tautological line bundle). It has a Hermitian metric, the Euclidean metric of $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$ restricted to each line, and the curvature of this metric is a symplectic form on $\mathbb{P}^n$. Note however that it is the opposite of the Fubini-Study form, which is the symplectic form commonly used on $\mathbb{P}^n$.
